# ng-grid doesn't updated ui

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

at first time ng-grid show my data very well, but when user change input form and then application get new data via ajax call, ng-grid data doesn't updated.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'gridData',
    plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin()],
    showFooter: true
};
$scope.gridData = [];

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/risk',
        data: criteria,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
            var gridData = [];
            response.list.forEach(function (e, i) {
                if (criteria.measureType == 'risk')
                    gridData.push({'risk': e.riskFactor, "bank": e.bank});
                else if (criteria.measureType == 'centrality')
                    gridData.push({"centrality": e.centrality, "bank": e.bank});
            });

        }

        $scope.gridData = angular.copy(gridData);
        $scope.$apply()
});
```

neigher [ng-grid doesn't update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791142/ng-grid-doesnt-update-data) nor [AngularJS/ng-grid - Updating array with splice doesn't updates UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529559/angularjs-ng-grid-updating-array-with-splice-doesnt-updates-ui) couldn't any help.
what is my mistake. tanhks

Comment: Did you try: `$scope.gridOptions.data = angular.copy(gridData)` ?

Comment: Could you try to create an [mcve]? Would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: or wrap `$scope.gridData = angular.copy(gridData);` with `$timeout` 0?

Comment: Tank you for reply,l tried it but my problem didn't solve

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Ui grid. We are using broadcast for updating the grid data as soon we change or want to refresh data

Comment: I'll check it a.s.a.p . Thank you

Comment: $rootScope.$broadcast('gridData',$scope.gridData); It doesn't help